# How to create multiple subfolders in a particular folder with an iterating loop

Tags: batch, cmd.exe

I want to create 25 different folders with specific names into one particular folder. I know how to create a folder with subfolders but not with multiple folder names in an iterating batch or command prompt loop.

**Example:** `root\sound\weapons\ak,m4,m1,m45,m9, etc.`

How can I array or loop iterate such a task with batch logic?

Comment: Please see my answer and let me know if it helped you resolve your issue? If so, feel free to check the little gray check mark to close it.

Comment: Do you mean you want 25 folders under root\sound\weapons\ ? Do the different folders have a sequence name or is there a list of names?

Answer (score 1):

> **How to create folders in one folder with batch**
>
> Hello i want to create 25 folders with names into one folder. example:
>   root\sound\weapons\ak,m4,m1,m45,m9 etc.
>
> I know how to create a folder with sub folders but not with multiple
>   folders.
>
> How i can array with batch.

### **Command Prompt Copy and Paste**

```
FOR %A IN (ak,m4,m1,m45,m9) DO MD "root\sound\weapons\%~A"
```

### **Batch Script**

```
FOR %%A IN (ak,m4,m1,m45,m9) DO MD "root\sound\weapons\%%~A"
```

**Notes:** In the logic part above where you see `IN (ak,m4,m1,m45,m9)` you will put the folder names in there separated by commas which you want to create. The `root\sound\weapons\` could also be `C:\Path\Path\` or something like that as well.

### Further Reading and Resources

- [**MD**](http://ss64.com/nt/md.html)
- [**FOR**](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html)

Comment: In `%~A` the `~` is not needed, you can just use `%A` (The `~` is only required if there are quotes in the variable `%A` that need to be removed). See parameters](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)

Comment: @DavidPostill I typically always try to keep the tilde in there in case there is other logic where double-quotes are around some other variable where that `~` parses the double quotes out so that's really just out of habit but it still works with or without it regardless but I agree in this particular instance it is not needed but it will still work with it -- strictly a habit thing I use as a standard typically as not having it has got me more than having it.